# How many laptops can I carry to India from Australia without Duty

Tags: import-taxes, customs-and-immigration

I am travelling to Australia on SC 400 Visa and have will have a short stay of 40 days or below.

I have to carry an office laptop with me. I also have a personal laptop. I am planning to buy a Macbook from Australia before returning.

Will duty be aplicable in India on return since I would be having 3 laptops with me when I come back!!

As per customs "One laptop computer (notebook computer) over and above the said free allowances mentioned above is also allowed duty free if imported by any passenger of the age of 18 years and above.". Since I will be taking the initial 2 laptops from India I will make sure I take an export certificate. So does this mean the macbook I buy from there will be duty free (since the other two would be in the export list) regardless off the cost of the mac.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Aren't electronics super expensive in Australia ?

Comment: Computers in Australia are definitely more expensive than in USA but they're cheaper than in some other places. I always saw lots of Indians at the electronics markets in Seoul where the prices were not better than in Australia though so maybe they are more expensive in India.

Comment: I added a "duty" tag which seems better than the "import tax" one. Then again we already have a "tax" tag with much more usage.

Comment: laptops are far far more expensive in India (although "components" and stuff are far cheaper in India.)